# Horizontal ScrollView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="An"
                        android:id="@+id/textView1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Codificare
Disciplina"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView2"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Denumire"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Curs"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView4" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Seminar"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Laborator"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView6"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Proiect"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView7" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar Credite"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView8" />



                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't add multiple rows in this table because i got errors like SrollView can hold only one parent at once and when i try to solve it the row goes vertically in column. Please help me.
I just tried all the solutions and i can't make it works. I don't know why i tried to solve this with solution find on stackoverflow and sites like this but i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting height = 0dp in your rows. Change this

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Tested with 2 rows, all worked as aspected for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="An"
                        android:id="@+id/textView1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Codificare
Disciplina"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView2"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Denumire"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Curs"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView4" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Seminar"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Laborator"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView6"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Proiect"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView7" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar Credite"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView8" />



                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="An"
                        android:id="@+id/textView21" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Codificare
Disciplina"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView22"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Denumire"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView23" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Curs"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView24" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Seminar"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView25" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Laborator"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView26"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar ore
Proiect"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView27" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Numar Credite"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/TexView28" />



                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

What's your problem?

Comment: I want to add another 8 rows like this i just created, i need to have a table with 15 rows. I done 1 row but i need more 14 under that. I tried to change that but doesn't work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Updated answer, if does not solve please post an example of your broken code

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="An"
                   android:id="@+id/textView1" />

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="CodificareDisciplina"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/TexView2"/>

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="Denumire"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/TexView3" />

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="Numar oreCurs"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/TexView4" />

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="Numar oreSeminar"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/textView5" />

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="Numar oreLaborator"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/TexView6"/>

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="Numar oreProiect"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/TexView7" />

                <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textAppearance="android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:text="Numar Credite"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:id="@+id/TexView8" />

      </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Caca"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Caca"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />

    </TableRow>




</RelativeLayout>
```

i add this after my code, another row appear but when i move LinearLayout and Scrollview the enhance all code my text goes on first row at the end. I tried all that you told me but doesn't work.